# Changing the background-color of the selected portion in popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a popup in which if I click on the question mark image, it is able to create a box contanining list of text. The fiddle for it is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9mj9g7y/7/)

I want the text to look in the following way:

[image]

> I am able to create a box containing list of text as shown in the
>   [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9mj9g7y/7/) but I am not sure how to change the background color of the selected portion text (eg: Support, Contact, Demo) .

For example, if I select or click or point the mouse to **Support** then the background-color of the **Support** text portion should be orange and the rest of them should be black or If I select or click or point the mouse to  **Contact** then the background-color of the rest of the text should be black with **Contact** text having orange background.

Below are the HTML and CSS snippets from the fiddle:

**HTML snippet:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="https://s27.postimg.org/40rb1a2ir/questionmark2.jpg" alt="homeicon">
<div class="popuptext" id="div">
     <div><span id="myPopup">Support</span><br/></div>
     <div><span id="myPopup1">Contact</span><br/></div>
     <div><span id="myPopup2">Demo</span><br/></div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
   var popup = document.getElementById('div');
popup.classList.toggle('show');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Snippet:**

```
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #FD8B00;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;

    padding:8px 10px 10px 120px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -225%;
    left: -52px;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#FD8B00 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So my answer below will tell you how to change the background-color when a button is clicked. Assume you have below CSS code.

```
#div div.selected {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Then, as the user click a button, you need to remove the previously selected button and change the background-color of currently selected button. You can achieve that using jQuery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div div').click(function(){
    $('#div div.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

You can also check out the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9mj9g7y/11/).. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will do it.

I re-created the markup to make it more better. Since the items are links (expecting to be links). I used `ul li a`.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#clicker').click(() => {
     $('.dialog-box').fadeToggle();      
  });

  $('.dialog-box li').click((e) => {
    var self = e.currentTarget;
    
    if(!$(self).hasClass('active')){
      $('.dialog-box .active').removeClass('active');
      $(self).addClass('active');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  margin: 50px 0 0 200px; 
  font-family: sans-serif; }

a#clicker {
  margin-left: 80px; }

ul.dialog-box {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: #434343;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px; }

ul.dialog-box:before {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ff8a00; }

ul.dialog-box li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  cursor: pointer; }

ul.dialog-box li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #787878; }

ul.dialog-box li.active {
  background: #ff8a00; }

ul.dialog-box li a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="clicker">Clicker</a>

<ul class="dialog-box">
    <li class="active"><a>Support</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a>Demo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible that after clicking on clicker, the background-color(orange) on the Support, Contact and Demo text should show up after taking the mouse there ? Example, if I take my mouse to Support then the background color in the "Support" text portion should come as Orange or if I take my mouse to "Contact" then  the background color at the "Contact" text portion should come as orange and vice-versa.

Comment: @shortcut If that's your case. Use `hover`

Comment: Check the https://jsfiddle.net/8vknhace/5/ I tried using hover but unfortunately its working properly when I am taking my mouse towards "Support"  text portion but not in "Contact" and "Demo" text portion. Also, Is it possible for the popup to go off after clicking outside of the popup section ?

Comment: @shortcut it should be `ul.dialog-box li:hover` not `ul.dialog-box li.active:hover `.

Comment: @shortcut Please update your question. So, we can answer exactly what you want. Sorry for late reply. I'm always busy at work.